# Sending strings from Visual Studio 2010 to Android

Tags: android, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to send a string from an application in Visual Basic 2010 to an Android app.
the code is the following

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Button4.Click
    Dim invio(TextBox3.Text.Length + 1) As Byte
    invio = UTF8.GetBytes(TextBox3.Text + " ")
    cliente = New TcpClient
    cliente.Connect("192.168.1.3", 5000)
    cliente.GetStream.Write(invio, 0, invio.Length)
End Sub
```

but when i send something the Android app receives the string very slowly (it takes about 10 minutes to receive a short string), and most of the times it doesn't even receive it.
If I try to send something from an Android app, the string is received almost immediately, so i think the problem is in the vb code... i hope you can help me!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

i just added
cliente.flush()
cliente.close()
under
cliente.GetStream.Write(invio, 0, invio.Length)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Flush()` the stream.

Otherwise, your data will sit in its internal buffer until the stream decides to send it over the network.

Comment: @Pitr: After writing the data that you want to flush.

Comment: Nothing has changed. I added flush() at cliente.getstream under "cliente.getstream.write(invio, 0, invio.Length)" but it's still very slow